# How to change citation style \parencite from squared to round brackets?

Tags: biblatex

This is what I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} 
  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage[backend=bibtex, 
  citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=100,
    firstinits=true,
    % natbib=true,
    sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{library}
          \usepackage{booktabs}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf,format=plain,parindent=1em]{caption}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \setkomafont{title}{\normalfont}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
    \linespread{1.25}
 \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
  % always last first
  \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

  \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
    \DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {title}{#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printtext[parens]{% 
        \printfield{labelyear}%
        \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

  \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
    \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {%\printtext[parens]{%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
      {\printdateextralabel}%
      {\printfield{labelyear}%
        \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

    \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
      %
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      %\printlist{publisher}% 
        %\setunit*{\addperiod\space}% 
        %
      \printlist{location}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
      \usebibmacro{date}%
      \newunit}

  \renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
    \printlist{institution}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
  \renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{%
    \printlist{organization}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

  \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield[parens]{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

    \begin{document}

    \cite{x}
    \parencite{y} 

    \end{document}
```

In the text it looks alright when I use `cite`, i.e. it looks like '...Author (Year) says...' or '...Author et al. (Year) say...'

However, now I want to cite within brackets in the following style: '...(Author et al., 1985)...' Can I somehow accomplish this?

When I use cite, it would look like '...(Author et al. (1985))...' and when I use `\parencite` it looks like (Author et al., [1985]) - so the squared brackets are not intended here.

edit: please close. Follow up thread here:
[How to cite in chicago style with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356446/how-to-cite-in-chicago-style-with-biblatex)

Indeed I made a new account, which was stupid. I thought I could not use my other tex account here somehow/I could not post at the beginning. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give the code of a *complete* document, including `\begin{document}`, `\cite{...}`, `\parencite{...}` and `\end{document}`. When I complete your document in the obvious way, I obtain `author year` (without parentheses) for `\cite` and `(author year)` (with round parentheses) for `\parencite`. So you must be doing something differently. Or you use some old version of the style files. My version, quite recent, is `biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7`.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP decided to ask the same/a revised question with another account, see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356446/how-to-cite-in-chicago-style-with-biblatex and the proposed edit to this question.

Comment: @gernot I agree, the revised question is also deleted. Even, maybe, delete this altogether.